# Why might my M1 Mac running Ventura not connect to the same strong Wi-Fi signal my cheap Android phone easily connects to?

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, mac, macos-ventura

I've got an expensive (by my standards) M1 MacBook with upgraded RAM and SSD running Ventura 13.1. I also have a cheap Redmi 10C phone running Android 12 with MIUI Global 13.0.5.

I'm in a chain coffee shop in Taipei with a very strong Wi-Fi signal.

My phone connects effortlessly to the Wi-Fi. My Mac will not. I have previously connected to very many signals with no problems on both devices.

I can't get any useful results out of Wireless Diagnostics. (In fact it locked up and my Mac reconnected to another signal with an ad-supported captive portal.

My phone tells me the Wi-Fi signal is WPA/WPA-Personal. No proxy. DHCP. Randomized MAC.

What are the most likely reasons the Mac won't connect to the Wi-Fi signal that the cheap phone can connect to easily?

(If this belongs on the Apple site I'll move it, but since it also concerns Android I thought Superuser was the most appropriate site.)

Comment: This [article](https://osxdaily.com/2022/12/12/m2-m1-macbook-having-wi-fi-issues-this-workaround-helps/) recommends using `sudo ifconfig awdl0 down`. See also [this advice](https://www.businessinsider.com/guides/tech/why-wont-my-mac-connect-to-wifi?r=US&IR=T).

Comment: Its vaguely the other way around, The mac is on topic, the Phone isn't. What band? 2.4 or 5ghz? Might need more information to answer but that's a start

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: How would I find out the band? I included most of the info on the signal I could get from my phone except: `Technology: Wi-Fi 4` and `Connection speed: 72Mbps`

Comment: Wifi 4 is 802.11n (cause leaving the old names well alone isn't good enough ._.)

Comment: Go to settings/wifi on your phone and you should see something like this - top is dualband, second one with no explicit band listed is 2.4 and the last is 5 ghz

Comment: @JourneymanGeek There is nothing like that in its Wi-Fi settings but in the specs there is this: `Baseband version: MPSS.HA.1.1.c1-00027-KD_ALL_PACK-3.20310.3`

Answer (score 2):

802.11n (a.k.a. "N", "Wi-Fi 4") and later don't work with original WPA (or the earlier WEP). So everything introduced in 2007 or later requires WPA2 or later at a minimum (or no wireless encryption at all).

If someone has set up an N or later network with only original WPA for security, it's an invalid network configuration. The Wi-Fi Alliance's certification tests—to qualify a product to call itself Wi-Fi and use the logo—specifically ensure client devices won't try to join using N or faster rates if original WPA is required.

So from the information you've provided so far, it could be that your MacBook is more Wi-Fi compliant than your cheap phone.

If the network allowed A/B/G (that is, if it didn't insist on N or later) then your MacBook might join in A or G mode with original WPA, which was a valid config from the fairly early days of Wi-Fi, but has a max signaling rate of 54Mbps, which worked out as real-world throughputs. after overhead, of 15-20Mbps.

Nowadays all networks should require WPA2 or later and not allow any form of original WPA or WEP.

Comment: hm. I don't have any redmi devices but OP *could* check with their phone which WPA standards the wifi AP supports I think

Comment: @spiff: Ah that's the kind of thing I was suspecting without knowing any of the actual jargon or tech. But it seems very odd that the Mac doesn't offer me any error message to say so if not give me the option of joining despite the security.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: If AP is "access point" isn't that the info I already included (WPA/WPA-Personal) or is there some way to dig deeper?

Comment: Naw, I think Spiff's right - and I kinda missed you posting it was WPA 1 only.